# ERROR 1105 (HY000): #07000MySQL Proxy Lua script failed to load. Check the error log

Tags: mysql, proxy, lua

This is my first time using mysql-proxy to learn how to use cryptdb and I am using the ubuntu 12.0.4.3
I have created a proxy using

```
--proxy-backend-addresses=localhost:3306
--proxy-address=127.0.0.1:3307
```

However, when I'm trying to connect to this proxy it said that `ERROR 1105 (HY000): #07000MySQL Proxy Lua script failed to load. Check the error log.`
Does anyone know the reason of this problem?
Thanks for any illumination!

Comment: *"**Check the error log.** Does anyone know the reason?"* Did you check the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path of the lua script? Specify your $EDBDIR by `export EDBDIR=<the-path-to-your-lua-file>` If you need to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: That's right. Do check the error log. But since it's running the proxy for the first time, I assume no changes made in the Wrapper.lua. Probably the $EDBDIR is not addressed. Rmb to read the cryptdb/doc  :)